# Правая граница текста в UIlabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Есть у меня некий _label в который я вывожу результат. Охото мне сделать так, что бы текст был чуточку слева от правой границы. Есть способ это сделать не прибегая к велосипедам или вообще через инспектор атрибутов?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Оберните UILabel в UIView. Установите trailing constraint между UILabel и UIView с нужным вам отступом. borderColor и cornerRadius задавайте не у UILabel, а у UIView.

Comment: Так обычно и делается. Даже если взять к примеру UIButton - внутри контент отображается отдельными UILabel и UIImageView, что позволяет управлять отступами.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, хорошим решением будет создание своего класса, наследующего UILabel, с переопределенным методом drawText:

```
class UILabelWithInsets: UILabel {
    public var textInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay() // вызывает drawText после установки отступов
        }
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, textInsets))
    }
}
```

Устанавливаем нашей UILabel класс UILabelWithInsets в storyboard и коде и задаем необходимые отступы:

```
label.textInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 5)
```